# onDestroy on IntentService is not called while using thread lock

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-intentservice

I have an activity which has a button. Clicking on the button will start an asynctask and shows a progress loader on the activity.

This asynctask has some things to do but before that it has to make sure all the `IntentService`s of the app are finished handling intents from their queue.

I approached this problem by creating a lock object as below.

```
public class Lock{

    private boolean isLocked = false;

    public synchronized void lock()
            throws InterruptedException{
        while(isLocked){
            wait();
        }
        isLocked = true;
    }

    public synchronized void unlock(){
        isLocked = false;
        notify();
    }
}
```

An intent Service which is doing something will create an instance of `Lock`. It holds the lock in a public static field so that others can access it. It will call lock on the object above in `onCreate()` and will call unlock in `onDestroy()`. The asynctask will call `lock` on the same `Lock` object.

The expectation here is that my asynctask will wait till `unlock()` is called on the `Lock` object in `onDestroy()` of the service.

But the problem I am facing is that `onDestroy()` is never called on the IntentService. Android throws anr as `ANR in <pkg>  Reason: Executing service`.

Can someone point out the problem in my understanding and implementation?

Comment: Of course - the thread waiting on the lock **is inside a synchronized block** so no other thread can run the unlock() method that it is synchronized with, but rather will be blocked waiting for the infinite loop to exit.

Comment: In that case atleast the onDestroy method of IntentService should have been called right? On testing the code further, I could produce a scenario where `onDestroy` on intentService will get called. It seems the problem I am seeing is related more with the asynchronous callbacks that are inter vined. I will simplify the code and get back with more details.

Comment: Android can't call another UI method such as onDestroy() when the UI thread is blocked trying to get the synchronization mutex to execute the unlock() call you've already made on it.  When Android detects the UI thread has been blocked for more than a short amount of time, it generates an ANR dialog.  You need to re-work your whole flag scheme to one that won't deadlock - a web search should find you examples.

Comment: Finally found the root cause of the problem. My asynctask was initiating a connection to GoogleApi (for location update). This connection is established asynchronously. I was waiting on the the IntentService to finish in the callback `onConnected()`. 

When I refactored the code to first wait for IntentService to finish and then initiate connection to GoogleApi, my `lock()` and `unlock()` methods started working fine. My understanding of how exactly asynchronous callbacks are handled in android is rusty, may need some help!

Comment: No - you might have fixed the *typical* delay, but your locking scheme still has the UI thread waiting on a potentially lengthy background operation, and that is not acceptable on Android (or from a design perspective, anywhere else either).